# Rewrite rules in ANTLR primaryExprList (OR^ primaryExprList)*

Tags: compiler-construction, antlr

can someone help me here, i am in stuck with this:

```
primaryExprList ('|'^ primaryExprList)*
```

I want to make it instead of '|' to use BOOLEANOR

comment for Vojislav Stojkovic:

I have tried it but it wont work correctly when i use a|b|c it should be like this

```
    BOOLEANOR
      |        \
BOOLEANOR        c
|      |
a      b
```

and your soultion is like this:

```
       BOOLEANOR
   /       |      \
  a        b       c
```

which is not coorect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't really see the need. If you define a `BOOLEANOR` token (lexer rule):

```
parse     : primaryExprList ('|'^ primaryExprList)*;
// or:      primaryExprList (BOOLEANOR^ primaryExprList)*

BOOLEANOR : '|';
```

then the type of the root with be `BOOLEANOR` and its inner text is `"|"`.

But, to answer your question (or propose a solution), the way to really change the root, is by using a rewrite rule like this:

```
grammar T;

options {
  output=AST;
}

tokens {
  OTHER;
}

parse
 : expr EOF!
 ;

expr
 : (e1=primaryExprList -> $e1) ('|' e2=primaryExprList -> ^(OTHER $expr $e2))*
 ;

// other rules
```

which will parse the input: "a|b|c" into the following AST:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Would this help?

```
primaryExprList ('|' primaryExprList)* -> ^(BOOLEANOR primaryExprList+)
```

Or did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: check my question again, there is a comment for u. I couldnt post an answer because of reputation restriction, and in comment i couldt write the tree